# Access callback in React

Tags: reactjs

Google API JS library returns a callback on successful load.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=callback"></script>
```

Can someone explain how to integrate this callback into React application with server-side rendering?
In vanilla js it will something like this:

```
function callback() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({...});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you're doing. Let's assume you want to enact a state change on that callback. You could put the following in your React component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return; // client side only
    }
    window.callback = () => {
        this.setState({
            isAuthorized: true
        });
    };
}
```

Just make sure this callback is defined before you call the remote resource. i.e. Put your React scripts before the Google script.

Comment: Hmm... even if render function returns false I should include component declaration into the html code, correct? Is it possible to achieve the same thing without doing this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking here. Perhaps you might like to provide some detail on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I wrote a component, here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/t9d2d2gp/ Now I can use it like this: import api from 'comp'. Question is, how to use it without adding html tags <api></api>

Comment: You don't need to create a brand new React component. Simply define the above `componentWillMount` within one of your existing React components.

Comment: Well it is an API, so I thought about defining API service, so I can call it from different parts of my code.

Comment: You can't really re-use a service that's embedded in a script tag. (At least not in a straightforward manner.) The whole point of the JSONP callback is that it gets executed once.